# How to accept html content as a parameter to a helper function in MVC+Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I notice that some Razor functions take html content as parameters, eg.:

```
@section Scripts  {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            alert("aha");
        });
    </script>
}
```

This doesn't render the html content immediately rather Razor's Section() system stores it for later rendering.

I would like to write my own helper function which accepts html content in the same way, eg.:

```
@Html.MyCoolFunction {
    <div><stuff><blah>...
    dafsdfsa
    </blah></stuff></div>
}
```

I don't know what syntax would work, but presumably MyCoolFunction would accept an MvcHtmlString as a parameter and I can do what I want with it.

Is this possible?

Comment: sometimes Google is faster and easier then asking a question - http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/

Comment: this one is for mvc 4 - http://dotnethelpers.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-using-mvc-4-razor/

Comment: Are you serious? This was not my question. I know how to write helper functions, my question is how to receive block html content to a helper function as a parameter.

Comment: uh... undo the downvote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to work it out from intellisense & other code samples.

An extension function like this:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DoTwice(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<MvcHtmlString, HelperResult> htmlContent)
    {
        var x = htmlContent(new MvcHtmlString("")).ToHtmlString() +
                htmlContent(new MvcHtmlString("")).ToHtmlString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(x);
    }
```

Can be called & passed block html content, like this:

```
@Html.DoTwice(
    @<div>What happens??</div>
)
```

Output:

```
What happens??
What happens??
```